# A tool to extract all links from a web-page in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm starting writing in Python and is tasked with writing a simple tool that opens a web-page, collects all the URLs (both complete like `http://mail.com` and relative ones like `/mail/inbox`) and returns a list of them prefixed with the domain name. The code is below.

Could someone take a look and advise on what could've been better in terms of the code style, readability, general coding principles and code quality?

Appreciate your help!

```
import sys, requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urlparse

def main(argv):
    ''' Main '''
    links = []

    try:
        if len(argv) != 3:
            raise IndexError("Not enough arguments.")

        url = argv[2].rstrip('/')
        scheme = urlparse(url).scheme

        if argv[1].upper() in ['GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS', 'PUT', 'DELETE']:
            method = argv[1]
        else:
            raise ValueError("Method %s is not supported." % argv[1])

        r = requests.request(method, url, verify=False) # get the response
        url = r.url.rstrip('/') # if there was a redirect - acquire the URL from the response

        print('[+] Retrieving '+url)
        raw_html = r.content

        soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, "html.parser")

        # neat print headers
        print("[+] Received the response HTTP %d" % r.status_code)
        for header in r.headers:
            print(header + ':', r.headers[header])

        # gathering a list of hrefs and srcs
        for script in soup.find_all('script'):
            if not script == None:
                links.append(script.get('src'))
        for anchor in soup.find_all('a'):
            if not anchor == None:
                links.append(anchor.get('href'))
        for link in soup.find_all('link'):
            if not link == None:
                links.append(link.get('href'))
        for form in soup.find_all('form'):
            if not form == None:
                links.append(form.get('action'))

        links = list(filter(None, links)) # removing None src's

        links = [link for link in links if
                 not link[0] == '#' and
                 not urlparse(link).scheme in ['mailto', 'skype'] and
                 not link == '/'] # removing bookmarks, emails and skype and '/'

        links = [scheme + '://' + link[2:] if link[0:2] == '//' else
                 link if urlparse(link).scheme in ['http', 'https'] else
                 url + link if link[0] == '/' else
                 url+'/'+link for link in links] # appending URL value

    except Exception as e:
        print("[-] Something went wrong: %s" % e)

    except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
        print("[x] Exiting by user command")

    print("\n[+] %d Links extracted:" % len(links))
    for link in links:
        print(link)
    return links

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('[*] Starting the main module')
    main(sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Code style issues (from top to bottom)

- *imports* - you should properly [group imports as per PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) - in the first group you would have your system-level imports, then third-party libraries and then your local imports - all groups sorted alphabetically with a blank line between the groups:

  ```
  import sys
  from urllib.parse import urlparse

  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  import requests
  ```
- [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id33) should be enclosed into triple quotes, start with a capital letter and end with a dot. "Main" is though not a descriptive and useful documentation string - see if you can add details about what the function does
- *variable naming* - use descriptive variable names - `response` instead of `r`
- watch for [spaces around the operators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements)
- when comparing to `None`, [you should be using `is` and not `==`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257919/what-is-the-difference-between-is-none-and-none), e.g. `if anchor is not None` - you though actually don't need these comparisons - see below
- [avoid using bare exception clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14797375/771848)

#### Other improvements

- you should switch to [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) module instead of manually parsing and validating `sys.argv`
- you don't actually need checks against `None` and filtering the `links` list - you can enforce the presence of attributes this way:

  ```
  script_elements = [element['src'] for element in soup.select('script[src]')]
  anchor_elements = [element['href'] for element in soup.select('a[href]')]
  link_elements = [element['href'] for element in soup.select('link[href]')]
  form_elements = [element['action'] for element in soup.select('form[action]')]

  links = script_elements + anchor_elements + link_elements + form_elements
  ```
- if performance is critical, see if you can use `lxml` instead of `html.parser` (requires `lxml` module to be installed):

  ```
  soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
  ```
- see if you can join the current url with the relative link with [`urljoin()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urljoin) - might simplify the post-processing for the extracted links

Comment: much appreciated. This makes me learn the proper ways of doing things :)

Comment: [The `requests` documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) uses `r` as a variable name for `requests.get`. Is this a valid reason for using single-letter variables or would you still recommend `request`?

Comment: @Coal_ good catch! It is probably not a big deal for this particular code snippet, but overall I would make a habit of making descriptive variable names unless you are doing a quick prototype. Thanks.